# optimisticconcurrencyexception was caught when updating entity relation using stub entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This code is giving me optimisticconcurrencyexception was caught.  I am simply using a Stub Entity to get an existing record and trying to update a couple values.  I am not sure how to resolve the exception.  Any help is very much appreciated:

```
using (MiscEntities ctx = new MiscEntities())  
{  
    var m = ctx.Rates.FirstOrDefault(m => m.UserId == UserIdGuid);      
    DataAccess.Rate oldDbRate = new DataAccess.Rate { RatingId = m.RatingId };    
    ctx.AttachTo("Rates", dbRate);  
    dbRate.Rating = Rating;  
    dbRate.DateLastModified = DateTime.Now;                      
    ctx.SaveChanges();  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF, by default, uses an optimistic concurrency model, meaning that locks are not held on data in the source between when the data is queried and when it is updated. So it doesn't check for any conflicts before saving changes to the database. With any conflicts an OptimisticConcurrencyException is raised (for more information check out [How to: Manage Data Concurrency in the Object Context](http://rlm.cc/gXg9HJ)).

It's good practice (when you make updates in a high concurrency scenario) to call [Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896255.aspx) quite often. In this case try using a [RefreshMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.refreshmode.aspx) of ClientWins to to refresh the values in the client store before sending them to the database, like this:

```
using (MiscEntities ctx = new MiscEntities())
{
    try
    {
        var m = ctx.Rates.FirstOrDefault(m => m.UserId == UserIdGuid);
        DataAccess.Rate oldDbRate = new DataAccess.Rate { RatingId = m.RatingId };
        ctx.AttachTo("Rates", dbRate);
        dbRate.Rating = Rating;
        dbRate.DateLastModified = DateTime.Now;
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException)
    {
        ctx.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, dbRate);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }                
}
```

**EDIT:** After more reading, and re-reading that error message it makes sense, you cannot attach an object to an ObjectContext is that object has already that has already been cached by the ObjectStateManager.

The solution is real simple, attach your objects **before** doing any operations/query in your ObjectContext. This allows you to prevent any double-tracking requests.  If the ObjectContext needs your Entity later, it will retrieve the instance you attached before and you're good to go. Take a look at this code and see if it helps (Sorry don't have Visual Studio 2010 opened right now)

```
using (MiscEntities ctx = new MiscEntities())
{
    try
    {
        ctx.AttachTo("Rates", dbRates);

        var m = ctx.Rates.FirstOrDefault(m => m.UserId == UserIdGuid);
        DataAccess.Rate oldDbRate = new DataAccess.Rate { RatingId = m.RatingId };

        dbRate.Rating = Rating;
        dbRate.DateLastModified = DateTime.Now;
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException)
    {
        ctx.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, dbRate);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
```

}
}

Comment: Thanks, but it is failing on the AttachTo method.  It says "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key."  Any idea how to resolve?

Comment: @obautista take a look at my edited answer and see if that helps resolve your issues ;)

Comment: I noticed a typo in my original post.  "oldDbRate" should just be "dbRate" where I define the Stub Entity.  I dont have my laptop in front of me right now, but in your suggestion how can I attach the object before it's defined?  It is being defined 2 lines below where you indicate to Attach it.  Basically what I am trying to do is if the record exists, I want to "update" it.  If not, I insert a new record.  That's the reason for getting "m" variable.  Thanks again for the help.