# OptimisticConcurrencyException on a database update

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

I have this vote method on a API i'm working on (I am sure there is plenty of room for improvement, all advice is appreciated).

I get this error:

*"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions."
ExceptionType:"System.Data.Entity.Core.OptimisticConcurrencyException"*

But everything seems to work fine

I add a new Vote object, with the voting user connected to it. And update the Post with a new nr of votes..

Can someone explain what goes wrong here? Perhaps advice to a solution

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/vote")]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(Post))]

    public IHttpActionResult Vote(string image_id, bool upVote)
    {
        // http://api.badgag.com/api/up/?image=123&upVote=true

        User user = new User(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims);
        if (user != null)
        {
            telemetry.Context.User.Id = user.user_id;
        }

        Post post = (from p in db.Posts where p.image.id == image_id select p).FirstOrDefault();

        // find post with image_id
        if (post == null)
        {
            // string message = "Could not find image";
            string message = "2";
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceWarning(message);
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, message));
        }

        if (post.creator.user_id == user.user_id)
        {
            // string message = "User cannot vote on his own post";
            string message = "3";
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceWarning(message);
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, message));
        }

        // TODO: find a faster way to look this up!
        foreach (Vote v in post.votes)
        {
            if (v.user.user_id == user.user_id)
            {
                // string message = "User already voted on this post";
                string message = "4";
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceWarning(message);
                throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, message));
            }
        }

        // add new vote
        Vote vote = new Vote();

        // if user does exist in db, add that object
        // if not, use new user object generated from claims
        vote.user = (from u in db.Users where u.user_id == user.user_id select u).FirstOrDefault();
        if (vote.user == null)
        {
            vote.user = user;
        }

        vote.upVote = upVote;
        vote.datetime = DateTime.Now;
        post.votes.Add(vote);

        // calc rating
        post.rating = new Rating();
        post.rating.datetime = post.image.datetime;
        post.rating.up = post.votes.Count(v => v.upVote == true);
        post.rating.down = post.votes.Count(v => v.upVote == false);
        post.rating.calc();

        // ERROR on saveChanges()
        /*
            "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). 
            Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. 
            See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions."

            ExceptionType: "System.Data.Entity.Core.OptimisticConcurrencyException"
         */

        // update post in DB
        db.SaveChanges();

        // remove sensitive info from Post before returning
        post.creator.email = "removed";
        post.creator.gender = "removed";
        post.creator.locale = "removed";
        post.creator.nickname = "removed";
        post.creator.picture = "removed";
        post.image.deletehash = "removed";
        post.votes.Clear();

        return Json(post);
        // return Json("user: " + user.user_id + " votes up image id: " + image);
    }
```

PS. This is from [badgag.com](https://badgag.com/), if you are interested in testing. Upload posts and vote :)

edit:
full error message

```
{Message: "An error has occurred.", ExceptionMessage: "An error occurred while saving entities that do no…entity types. See the InnerException for details.", ExceptionType: "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException", StackTrace: "   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.…tpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()", InnerException: {…}}
ExceptionMessage
:
"An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details."
ExceptionType
:
"System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException"
InnerException
:
ExceptionMessage
:
"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions."
ExceptionType
:
"System.Data.Entity.Core.OptimisticConcurrencyException"
Message
:
"An error has occurred."
StackTrace
:
"   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ValidateRowsAffected(Int64 rowsAffected, UpdateCommand source)
↵   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
↵   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
↵   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)
↵   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
↵   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35()
↵   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
↵   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
↵   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27()
↵   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
↵   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
↵   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
↵   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()"
__proto__
:
Object
Message
:
"An error has occurred."
StackTrace
:
"   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
↵   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
↵   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
↵   at Api.Controllers.PostController.Vote(String image_id, Boolean upVote) in C:\git\secureapi\Api\Controllers\PostController.cs:line 95
↵   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
__proto__
:
Object
```

Comment: On what line did you receive that exception? Do you understand what **optimistic concurrency** is and how it differs from **pessimistic concurrency**?

Comment: @mjwills the line where I do db.saveChanges() I assume, I need to read up on concurrency I think.

Comment: `I assume` It would really help if you could **confirm** that is where the exception is occurring @ganjan . Also, does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789371/optimisticconcurrencyexception-was-caught-when-updating-entity-relation-using-st help?